# Gitlab-ci Docker login Heroku Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Tags: docker, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to push image from GitLab registry to Heroku image registry, but I am unable to login in gitlab-ci.

Firstly, locally I was able to log in successfully. I was following this guide - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#logging-in-to-the-registry. The log-in was successful:

```
docker login --username=_ --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/dave/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
```

When I try to do the same in my gitlab-ci.yml file I receive error message trying both of these options:

```
script:
    - docker login --username=_ --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
```

OR

```
script:
    - echo $HEROKU_API_KEY | docker login --username=_ --password-stdin registry.heroku.com
```

Error message:

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Are there other methods I should use to log in via gitlab-ci to Heroku image registry?

Update:
The HEROKU_API_KEY env variable is set up correctly. It is not masked, not protected and available in all environments. I was even able to use it previously with another command to deploy, but this time I must deploy a docker container.
Another command that was used:

```
- dpl --provider=heroku --app=my-app --api-key=$HEROKU_SECRET_KEY
```

That being said, I still need a solution to deploy the container from the Gitlab registry to the Heroku registry but the docker login fails.

Comment: If you're sure the key is set in the project CICD variables and is correct: try quoting: `--password="${HEROKU_API_KEY}"`

Comment: @sytech Hi, tried docker login --username=_ --password="${HEROKU_API_KEY}" registry.heroku.com but unfortunately it returned the same error in my question

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises from the environment variable `HEROKU_API_KEY` not being configured  or available in the ci.

I recognize the problem since I ran into the exact same situation.
The error message says "interactive login not possible" because it received an empty input in stdin. Normally this is run in a shell, you could fill in the password manually, so docker presumes that this is what you wanted to do, however since stdin closes, it can't get the password. Well, that's just the explanation for the message you're getting.

As for what actually causes the variable not being available, there is a few possibilities:

- Maybe you didn't configure the variable in the project settings yet.
  For that, go to your settings, to the CI section, to variables, and enter the variable with name and value.
- Maybe the variable is protected, and you're trying to use it in a pipeline that can't use protected variables. In this case, you can uncheck the setting for the "protected" state of the variable, in the same menu as described in the above point.
  Alternatively you can check whether you might want to leave it be protected, but switch to only using the variable in a setting that can use protected variables.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, the issue is not with the env variable. It is not masked, not protected and available in all environments. I will update my question with this information.
Also I think this kind of error message means something else than incorrect log in details.

Comment: If it's not this, then I doubt I can help. And, the error message is exactly what you would get if you would `echo "" | docker login --username=_ --password-stdin registry.heroku.com`.  Maybe just to be sure, could you try logging out the length of the variable (with `${#HEROKU_API_KEY}`) to check that it's actually there?